# How to deploy dockerised Flask web app on a subdomain

Tags: wordpress, docker, flask, deployment, subdomain

I have a dockerised flask app and want to deploy it on a custom domain.

What I would like would be to create a Wordpress for the main website (presentation blog and everything to make it simpler) on mydomain.com and deploy my flask app on app.mydomain.com

First of all is it a good idea ? And if so what is the best way to connect both in a good way ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve the problem using a reverse proxy such as [nginx](https://www.nginx.com/).
By using nginx you will be able to redirect the request to the correct application depending on the domain it comes from.

pseudo nginx configuration:

```
 server {
        #your other config....

        #redirect all request from your.domain.com to your wordpress app.
        if ($host = your.domain.com) {
            #redirect traffic to wordpress upstream
        }

       #redirect all unsecure www to secure www
        if ($host = your.sub.domain.com) {
            #redirect traffic to flask upstream
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi @Matteo Pasini thanks for your reply ok it is clearer but do you recommend this ? Or it is a bad idea and it is better to create the whole website with flask. I’m not sure about the common practices about this …

Comment: Depends on your needs, you might as well implement everything under the same domain.